# Insert XML with more than 4000 characters into a Oracle XMLTYPE column

Tags: xml, oracle, insert, ora-01461, ora-20000

I have an oracle table with a column from type "`SYS.XMLTYPE`" and a storage procudure which is doing the insert:

(Short version):

```
PROCEDURE InsertXML 
(
     pXMLData IN LONG 
)
IS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (XML_DATA) VALUES(pXMLData);

END InsertXML;
```

I call this sp from my C# code with type "`OracleType.LongVarChar`".

Now the problem:
If the xml has less than 4000 characters everything is working fine, but by using a xml with more than 4000 characters I get the following error:

```
ORA-20000: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

How can I handle this?
Thx 4 answers

Comment: can help? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm#1035001

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Oracle docs about [XMLType](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm)

Also, I believe the datatype should be a CLOB (Character Large Object).

Comment: Thx, "CLOB" type was the answer :)

/closed

Comment: @Marco How did you fixed this? Can you please post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert xml string for more than 4000 charcaters into SQLXML type first.

Environment: jpa 2.1.0, eclipselink 2.5.2, oracle db 11gr2

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "XMLTEST"
( "ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "XML_TXT" "XMLTYPE" NOT NULL ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO XMLTEST (ID, DESCRIPTION, XML_TXT) VALUES (101, 'XML DATA', '<data>TEST</data>');
COMMIT;

DROP TABLE "XMLTEST";
```

Java Code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO XMLTEST (ID, DESCRIPTION, XML_TXT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
String xmlDataStr = "<data>test...</data>"; // a long xml string with length > 4000 characters
Connection con = getEntityManager().unwrap(Connection.class);
SQLXML sqlXml = con.createSQLXML();
sqlXml.setString(xmlDataStr);
```

Java code - use PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setLong(1, 201);
pstmt.setLong(2, "Long XML Data");
pstmt.setSQLXML(3, sqlXml);
pstmt.execute();
```

Java code - use native query instead of PreparedStatement

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, 301);
query.setParameter(2, "Long XML Data");
query.setParameter(3, sqlXml);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How can I convert xml string for more than 4000 charcaters into SQLXML type first?

Answer (score 0):

According to 
[Stuart Campbell](https://codetripper.wordpress.com/2006/07/16/ora-01461-when-inserting-into-an-oracle-xmltype-column/)

- I inserted a XMLTYPE into a CLOB
- but the statement itself had to be wrapped in a transaction.

Without transaction, it did not work....