# How do I insert more than 4000 characters into XmlType using OracleClientFactory?

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to insert a chunk of Xml that is larger than 4000 characters into an XmlType field in an Oracle table.

Originally my code worked like this:

```
DbParameter parameter = new DbParameter;
parameter = clientFactory.CreateParameter(":p_xml_data", DbType.AnsiString, messageToLog.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, messageToLog);
```

However as soon as I started trying to insert Xml blocks larger than 4000 bytes I got:

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

This is the same issue as this question [2508987/insert-xml-with-more-than-4000-characters-into-a-oracle-xmltype-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508987/insert-xml-with-more-than-4000-characters-into-a-oracle-xmltype-column), however I do not have DbType.Clob as an option (it doesn't exist).

Next I tried changing the type to DbType.Object, hoping it would just convert it to whatever it needed, but I get this message:

```
Cannot bind type System.String as Blob
```

Then I tried using DbType.XML, I modified my code to move the messageToLog into a SqlXml object:

```
SqlXml sx;
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(messageToLog);
using (XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc))
{
    sx = new SqlXml(xnr);
}
```

And changed the parameter accordingly:

```
parameter = providerFactory.CreateParameter(":p_xml_data", DbType.Xml, messageToLog.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, sx);
```

Now I get:

```
Value is not valid for DbType: Xml
```

Truely I just want to store larger blocks of XML in my column.

Answer (score 2):

You should the the [Oracle Docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featXML.htm#ODPNT0020) for the ODP.NET library, specifically for setting XMLType information. The `OracleXmlType` class and its uses are also [described](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleXmlTypeClass.htm#i1033889) separately. I'm not really a C# developer myself, so I can't give you exact code. [This is what I found](http://www.dotnetforce.com/Content.aspx?t=a&n=246) searching around, but I haven't tried it myself:

```
OracleCommand orainscmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO employees(empinfo) " +
" VALUES (:empinfoxml)", con);
orainscmd.Parameters.Add(":empinfoxml", OracleDbType.XmlType);
OracleXmlType xmlinfo = new OracleXmlType(con,doc);
orainscmd.Parameters[0].Value=xmlinfo;
orainscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

bind it like this:  .OracleDbType = OracleDbType.XmlType;

.DBType = DbType.Xml doesn't work and will throw a runtime error because the enumerated value is out of range.

see below:

```
    public void insertSimRun(OracleConnection conn, SliceDataExchange.ServiceReference1.SimulationRun simRun)
    {
        string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO slice_sim (runid, first_int_start, simulation_run) ";
        sqlInsert += "values (:p_runid, :p_interval_start, :p_simxml)";

        OracleCommand cmdInsertSR = new OracleCommand();
        cmdInsertSR.CommandText = sqlInsert;
        cmdInsertSR.Connection = conn;

        OracleParameter runID = new OracleParameter();
        runID.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        runID.Value = simRun.RunId;
        runID.ParameterName = "p_runid";

        OracleParameter first_interval_start = new OracleParameter();
        first_interval_start.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
        first_interval_start.Value = simRun.FirstIntervalStartUtc;
        first_interval_start.ParameterName = "p_interval_start";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SliceDataExchange.ServiceReference1.SimulationRun));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        //System.Xml.XmlDocument xdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

        serializer.Serialize(writer,simRun);

        //xdoc.LoadXml(writer.ToString());

        OracleParameter simRunXML = new OracleParameter();
        simRunXML.DbType = DbType.String;
        simRunXML.ParameterName = "p_simxml";
        simRunXML.Value = writer.ToString();
        simRunXML.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.XmlType;


        cmdInsertSR.Parameters.Add(runID);
        cmdInsertSR.Parameters.Add(first_interval_start);
        cmdInsertSR.Parameters.Add(simRunXML);

        cmdInsertSR.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmdInsertSR.Dispose();
    }
```